# phonegap database error code 5 - non an error

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova

I am using phonegap to access the phone database. But my create process calls everytime the error routine with error code: 5 and message: `non an error`?

Isn't it possible to execute multiple sql statements in one transaction?

SQLite Expert couldnt find an syntax error...

```
createDB: function(error, success) {
        if(typeof error != 'function') error = this.errorDB;
        if(typeof success != 'function') success = this.successDB;
        sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `boiler`; "
            +"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `boiler` ( "
            +" `id` int NOT NULL, `object` int NOT NULL, `number` varchar(100) NOT NULL, "
            +" `volume` double DEFAULT NULL, `brand` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL, "
            +" `price_before` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `price_after` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  `description` TEXT DEFAULT NULL, "
            +" `img1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `img2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `img3` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, "
            +" `img4` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `img5` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,  `img6` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, "
            +" `img7` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `img8` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `img9` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, "
            +"PRIMARY KEY (`id`)); "

            +"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `counter`; "
            +"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `counter` ( "
            +" `number` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `object` int NOT NULL, `type` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', "
            +" `value` double DEFAULT NULL, `access` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, "
            +"PRIMARY KEY (`number`)); "

            +"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `link`; "
            +"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `link` ( "
            +" `id` int NOT NULL, `boiler` int NOT NULL, `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, "
            +" `units` tinyint DEFAULT NULL, `price` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', "
            +"PRIMARY KEY (`id`)); "

            +"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `manager`; "
            +"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `manager` ( "
            +" `id` int NOT NULL, `company` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL, "
            +" `phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, "
            +"PRIMARY KEY (`id`)); "

            +"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `object`; "
            +"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `object` ( "
            +" `id` int NOT NULL,  `state` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `user` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, "
            +" `date` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,  `street` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `number` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL, "
            +" `zip` char(5) DEFAULT NULL, `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `manager` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', "
            +" `units` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', "
            +"PRIMARY KEY (`id`));";
        console.log(sql);
        this.DB.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(sql); }, error, success);
    },
```

Comment: if i split statements then there is no error, but can't i do all as one transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know the error code: 5  but you can execute the  multiple sql statements

```
         // Wait for PhoneGap to load

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // PhoneGap is ready

            function onDeviceReady() {
                var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
            }

            // Populate the database 

            function populateDB(tx) {
                 tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
                 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
                 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
                 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
        //here you can do  multiple sql statements.
            }

            // Transaction error callback

            function errorCB(err) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
            }

            // Transaction success callback

            function successCB() {
                alert("success!");
            }
```

[link here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction)

Comment: executeSql expects only one statement, thus error code 5, which means parsing error (reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#parsing-and-processing-sql-statements).

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your Database From File Explorer

there is problem only in the creation of table like you are entering four values but in your table there are only three columns so this error occours

tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  quotes(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name,flag INTEGER,address,description,phone_number,date INTEGER,quote_number,job,images)");

Error is due to if you are assigning directly integer value instead of var type value
like for flar i am using 1 or 0
but now i store this value in var type